# Regex pattern with XML tags

Tags: c#, regex, xml, winforms, ms-word

I'm using DocumentFormat.OpenXml NuGet to read Word documents.
In a document, there are text (let call it placeholders) like this ${someTextToReplace1} or ${someTextToReplace2}.

Ex. Today is ${dateHere}...

```
using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(document, true))
{
    string docText = null;

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()))
    {
        docText = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }

    Regex txtToReplace = new Regex("\\$\\{dateHere\\}", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    docText = txtToReplace.Replace(docText, DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());

    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create)))
    {
        sw.Write(docText);
    }
}
```

docText a string like this `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> <w:document xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office... <w:t>${dateHere}</w:t>...`

Sometimes instead of ${dateHere} there is some XML tags in between ${} like so

```
${</w:t></w:r><w:proofErr w:type="spellStart"/><w:r w:rsidRPr="00852006"><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" w:cs="Times New Roman"/></w:rPr><w:t>dateHere</w:t></w:r><w:proofErr w:type="spellEnd"/><w:r w:rsidRPr="00852006"><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" w:cs="Times New Roman"/></w:rPr><w:t>}
```

or

```
${</w:t></w:r><w:proofErr w:type="spellStart"/><w:r w:rsidRPr="00852006"><w:t>dateHere</w:t></w:r><w:proofErr w:type="spellEnd"/><w:r w:rsidRPr="00852006"><w:t>}
```

How to write regex pattern which will find those tags `${*dateHere*} or ${*dateHere} or ${dateHere*}`.

`* - represents XML tags`

Comment: There is an example with regex from the MSFT page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-search-and-replace-text-in-a-document-part

Comment: What should I use then to find and replace anything in between my search therm ${-SOMExmlTAGS-dateHere-SOMExmlTAGS-}?

Comment: I think what they are doing is a little bit different from what you are trying to do... I'll have a deeper look into that.

Comment: And it's just a Plain-Text Placeholder, not a Field, right?

Comment: I don't really understand how this happens: _"Sometimes instead of ${dateHere} there is some XML tags in between ${} like so"_. If it weren't for that, you should be able to find&replace just like in the example from MSFT (which isn't really working on the XML with the Regex but on the text contained).

Comment: Argh, wait... If you open that Doc in Word, does "dateHere" have squiggly lines from Spell-Check?

Comment: We have template_document_1.docx. When WordprocessingDocument ReadToEnd Sometimes instead of ${dateHere} there are some XML tags in between and sometimes not. But when the same template_document_1.docx is opened with LibreOffice Writer and saved without any changes as Word 2007-365 .docx then there are no XML tags in between and everything is just fine

Comment: `Argh, wait... If you open that Doc in Word, does "dateHere" have squiggly lines from Spell-Check?` No. ${dateHere} is just regular text

Comment: I upvoted the question. I hope this will be seen by someone more experienced with Word Docs & Open Xml. I still cannot come up with a reason why this might happen (and therefore with no solution, neither).

Comment: Relevant https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/14868997

Comment: Sounds like instead you should use OpenXML as it's supposed to be used: `wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Descendants().Where(x => x.LocalName == "document" && x.Descendants.Any(x2 => x2.LocalName == "t"))` or something like that